# zkSnarks: Why does the target polynomial $t(s)$ need to be kept a secret if it's known to both prover & verifier?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I am reading this explanation of zkSnark written by Maksym Petkus - http://www.petkus.info/papers/WhyAndHowZkSnarkWorks.pdf

The example used here is that there is a polynomial of degree 3 which the verifier knows has roots 1 & 2.

- The whole polynomial is $p(x)$
- The target polynomial $t(x) = (x-1)(x-2)$.
- The 3rd root comes from $h(x)$, i.e. if 3rd root is 3, then $h(x) = (x-3)$.
- And $p(x) = h(x). t(x)$.

So it seems the secret here that the prover proves to the verifier is his knowledge of $h(x)$

However, deep into the tutorial, in Section 3.6, where the author adds Non-Interactivity to the protocol, he says the following

> Till this point, we had an interactive zero-knowledge scheme. Why is
> that the case? Because the proof is only valid for the original
> verifier, nobody else (other verifiers) can trust the same proof
> since:
>
> - the verifier could collude with the prover and disclose those secret parameters $s$, $\alpha$ which allows to fake the proof, as mentioned
>   in remark 3.1
> - the verifier can generate fake proofs himself for the same reason
> - verifier have to store $\alpha$ and $t(s)$ until all relevant proofs are verified, which allows an extra attack surface with possible
>   leakage of secret parameters

I understand how $\alpha$ is a secret & needs to be protected but why does $t(s)$ need to be protected - in the interactive version, it was something known by both the prover & verifier, so why while adding Non-Interactivity to the protocol does $t(s)$ suddenly become a secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the polynomial $t(x)$ itself is known, the specific evaluation at $s$, $t(s)$, is not known.

In the interactive version, the prover computes $g^p$ and $g^h$ in "encrypted space" as the paper calls it, by using the "encrypted" powers of $s$.

The verifier then uses $t(s)$ to check that $g^p = g^{h \cdot t(s)}$, implying $p(x) = h(x) \cdot t(x)$ with high probability.

Because $t(x)$ is known, if $t(s)$ was also known, $s$ could be recovered. This is because the polynomial $t(x) - t(s)$ has $s$ as a root, by definition. Any algorithm that computes roots of polynomials modulo $q$, for example the [Cantor–Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) algorithm, could be used to find $s$. Thus, $t(s)$ must be kept secret.

In order to do so, we also encrypt $t(s)$ giving $g^{t(s)}$, and then use a bilinear pairing to perform the multiplication in the exponent of $g$.